# Devise. Migrating users from one app to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, migration

So I have two Rails applications. The old one is using devise (2.2.1) for authentication and the new one has devise (3.2.4). There is a huge amount of users (nearly 10k) in database.

Rails version of the old app is (3.2.11), the new one is (4.0.2).

What I need is to 'copy' every user from the old app to the new one.
And so I did. But now when I'm trying to log in it fails. Here's some logs:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 185.16.106.233 at 2014-05-09 06:45:24 +0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"?^?^?", "authenticity_token"=>"8d8yWlLPNcaITv5WqT5fgooAQCUOY6DIC1HiZPgslXM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"test.for.stats@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 16ms
```

I think there's a problem with password encryption. I tried to copy secret_token and pepper from the old app devise, but it didn't help.

Any ideas how to resolve this without mass password reset?

Thanks.

Comment: Try creating new user with same password and see if `encrypted_password` will be the same. If not that means either hash method changed (see Devise change log for that) or you forgot some hashing param (maybe Rails secret is used?)

Comment: I would do it at db-level. Download the users from the old db, and upload to the new db. Ensure the password encryption algo is the same with `@MichaelSzyndel`'s comment; if it is, you should be able to send the users no problem!

Comment: So yes, creating a new user (with the same password) showed that the encrypted_password field is different. Still can't figure out what could be the reason.